# how to work with several 'Pdcx' (x = 1 to 3) columns in csv file with python

Tags: python, csv

the Header looks like this:

blah;blah;blah;Pdc1;Pdc2;blah;......;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;blah;....Pdc1;blah;...;Pdc1

and so on, were as blah = rnd other entry.

with this code:

```
`import csv
i=0
location=[]
pdc = 'Pdc'
with open('export_min2.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    cr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =';')
    for row in cr:
        for x in row:
            if pdc in x:
                location.append(i)
            i=i+1
print(location)`
```

I get a List "Location" with all the numbers I need to adress the specific columns. I.e [7,8,17,18,27,28,29,37,56,and so on]

Now I use this code to build the average Pdc for each hour, where as I put all Pdcs which follow directly into 1 Element I call wrx:

```
`import csv
i =0
wr1=0
wr2=0
wr3=0
wr4=0
wr5=0
wr6=0
wr7=0
wr8=0
wr9=0
wr10=0
wr11=0
timeStamp=[]
with open('export_min2.csv', 'r') as csvfile, \
     open('Spalten_avg.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvout:
        cr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ';')
        cw = csv.writer(csvout, delimiter = ';')
        next(cr, None) # skip header
        for line  in cr:
            if timeStamp[3:5] == '00':  # new hour // ab und zu fehlen Werte es geht nicht immer in 5 Minuten Schritten!!!
                wr1 = wr1/i
                wr2 = wr2/i
                wr3= wr3/i
                wr4 = wr4/i
                wr5 = wr5/i
                wr6 = wr6/i
                wr7 =wr7/i
                wr8 =wr8/i
                wr9 =wr9/i
                wr10 = wr10/i
                wr11= wr11/i
                i=0
                cw.writerow([timeStamp,'%.2f' %wr1,'%.2f' %wr2,'%.2f' %wr3,'%.2f' %wr4,'%.2f' %wr5,'%.2f' %wr6,'%.2f' %wr7,'%.2f' %wr8,'%.2f' %wr9,'%.2f' %wr10,'%.2f' %wr11])
                wr1=0
                wr2=0
                wr3=0
                wr4=0
                wr5=0
                wr6=0
                wr7=0
                wr8=0
                wr9=0
                wr10=0
                wr11=0
            timeStamp = line[1]
            wr1 = int(line[7]) + int(line[8]) +wr1 # wr = Wechselrichter
            wr2 = int(line[17]) + int(line[18]) +wr2
            wr3 = int(line[27]) + int(line[28]) +wr3
            wr4 = int(line[37]) + int(line[38]) + int(line[39]) +wr4
            wr5 = int(line[49]) +wr5
            wr6 = int(line[58]) +wr6
            wr7 = int(line[67]) +wr7
            wr8 = int(line[76]) +wr8
            wr9 = int(line[85]) +wr9
            wr10 = int(line[94])+ wr10
            wr11 = int(line[103]) + wr11
            i= i+1`
```

Now if somebody would add another solar panel I would have to manually print that List again and manually add that number into the 2nd code. So this isn't going to work automatically if somebody makes changes(adds/removes) panels.

And I would like it to be automatically.

Is that possible?

Find each Pdcx columns and add them to another csv file maybe? But how? The problem is the header has always the same String and has 16 entries.... and those entries would vary.

Comment: So the first pass through the csv identifies the columns with Pdc in them, and the second pass you look only at those columns and accumulate the numbers. Why do wr1-3 accumulate pairs of numbers, wr4 accumulate three numbers, and wr5-11 take single numbers?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of sample data, and the expected output for that data?

Comment: This is the header:#Date;Time;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc

Comment: I want anything stat starts with a Pdc and the time column. I add every Number that follows directly i.e 37+38+39 because that is 1 module with 3 units. the rest has 2 units or only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so adjacent columns after a Pdc1 (unless they are another Pdc1) are ones you want to accumulate. Basically what you need to do is to construct a specification of the fields you want to collect, and accumulate, then read all the data following the specification. As you want to accumulate some adjacent columns, a simple list of columns won't work very well - but a list of a list of columns to accumulate sounds like it would do the trick.

Here's something I hope you can extrapolate from - note you will have to fix up the timestamp code in this, although I used column 1 (2nd column) - in the data I constructed I just put some random numbers in there so that when the number goes down from one row to the next that is like the hour rolling over.

**Updated with your real headings, and using column 1 for time:**

```
import random
import copy

#************************************
# construct some sample data
#headingline = ["timestamp","x","Pdc1","Pdc1","x","Pdc1","Pdc2","x","Pdc1","Pdc2","Pdc3","x"]

headingtext = 'Date;Time;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Udc1;Udc2;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Pdc2;Pdc3;Udc1;Udc2;Udc3;Uac;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc;INV;Pac;DaySum;Status;Error;Pdc1;Udc;Uac;Idc'
headingline = headingtext.split(";")

print headingline

NROWS = 30

# this is one line of data
dataline = [i for i in range(len(headingline))]
# data table has some copies of the dataline
datatable = [copy.copy(dataline) for i in range(NROWS)]
# insert some random values in the time column - when a smaller value is encountered, that's
# like rolling over an hour
for j in datatable:
    j[1] = random.random()

#************************************
# scan through headingline, looking for Pdcx
# scanfields will be a list of lists - one list for
#  each sequence of adjacent columns starting with Pdc1
scanfields = []
i = 0
while i < len(headingline):
    if headingline[i] == "Pdc1":
        # start collecting
        thisvalue = [i]
        i += 1
        while i < len(headingline) and "Pdc" in headingline[i] and "Pdc1" not in headingline[i]:
            thisvalue.append(i)
            i += 1
        # add the list of adjacent columns as one entry in the scanfields
        scanfields.append(thisvalue)
    else:
        i += 1
print "Input headings are:",headingline
print "columns to accumulate are:",scanfields

#************************************
# scan through the data, constructing the results
# initialise results to 0
wr = [0 for i in scanfields]
nreadings = 0
# put in an impossible value for lasttimestamp so that a rollover
# can't happen on the first reading 
lasttimestamp = -1
for line in datatable:
    timestamp = line[1]
    if timestamp < lasttimestamp:
        # we have rolled over an hour
        # output the results
        print lasttimestamp,wr
        # reset for start of accumulation
        wr = [0 for i in scanfields]
        nreadings = 0
    # accumulate some data
    for i,columns in enumerate( scanfields ):
        for column in columns:
            wr[i] += line[column]
    nreadings += 1
    lasttimestamp = timestamp

# if there is some, print any remaining data
if nreadings>0:
    print timestamp,wr
```

Output:

```
columns to accumulate are: [[7, 8], [17, 18], [27, 28], [37, 38, 39], [49], [58], [67], [76], [85], [94], [103]]
0.987937572095 [45, 105, 165, 342, 147, 174, 201, 228, 255, 282, 309]
0.593538271082 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.670491046198 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.632537644435 [15, 35, 55, 114, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 103]
0.56164680441 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.644908184199 [60, 140, 220, 456, 196, 232, 268, 304, 340, 376, 412]
0.489805407587 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.212797884434 [15, 35, 55, 114, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 103]
0.680429898554 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.566808432396 [15, 35, 55, 114, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 103]
0.998376984177 [60, 140, 220, 456, 196, 232, 268, 304, 340, 376, 412]
0.324205600344 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.849099671794 [30, 70, 110, 228, 98, 116, 134, 152, 170, 188, 206]
0.656450073231 [15, 35, 55, 114, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 103]
0.3526924274 [15, 35, 55, 114, 49, 58, 67, 76, 85, 94, 103]
```

HTH
Barny

Comment: Hi Barny thx for your help. I don't have much time now to go over your code in detail, but I would need another function in order to get the headingtext of each csv file since the length and position would change if somebody would add or remove a panel, am I right? But that isn't much of a problem. I will test your suggestion later, thanks again!

Comment: Yes - it's just fixed in my code to setup things to try this out - you can read the first row of the csv (just as you already do) and treat it as the headline. Similarly where I wrote 'for line in datatable' you would read data from the CSV.

Comment: Hi barny, I encountered another poblem. The Timestamp should give a value every 5 minutes. So 12 in a hour. However sometimes randomly a line is missing. it goes from 11:55 to 11:45. So I only get 11 values per hour. Now my professor wants me to interpolate the missing value (after I found it) and add it in the right place. Could you recommend a library for the interpolation?

Comment: err, use some arithmetic? It just involves the wraparound code - linear interpolate between previous time/value and latest time/value to report hour-aligned usage. have to handle the first and last readings carefully - do you extrapolate to the hour?

Comment: yeah I just found what I need. numpy's interpolation function is doing the job, thx for the response, though!